# order by with three conditions using mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a join query there are i need to record order by with three condition
  1. those record purch_order_workflow_code_nr = '3' come first 
  2. those record status= empty come second 
  3. after that come all reaming record

please give me a proper solution how should i write for this 
i have tried this code .on my query but i did not get what i want

```
SELECT purch_order.user_code_tx as user_code_tx ,purch_order.date_creation 
    as date_creation ,purch_order.purch_order_code_nr as purch_order_code_nr 
    ,purch_order.status as status ,purch_order.purch_order_workflow_code_nr as purch_order_workflow_code_nr ,ppod.vehicle_plate_tx as vehicle_plate_tx ,(Select pd.purch_order_detail_desc_tx from purch_order_detail pd where pd.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr limit 1 ) as purch_order_detail_desc_tx ,(Select pd.purch_order_workflow_desc_tx from purch_order_workflow pd where pd.purch_order_workflow_code_nr = purch_order. purch_order_workflow_code_nr limit 1 ) as purch_order_workflow_desc_tx ,vehicle.op_base_code_nr as op_base_code_nr ,company_division.div_name_tx as div_name_tx ,company_division_op_bases.op_base_name as op_base_name 
FROM purch_order inner join (Select distinct pod.purch_order_code_nr, pod.vehicle_plate_tx from purch_order_detail pod) ppod on ppod.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr inner join vehicle on vehicle.vehicle_plate_tx = ppod.vehicle_plate_tx inner join company_division on company_division.div_code_nr= purch_order.div_code_nr inner join company_division_op_bases on company_division_op_bases.op_base_code_nr = vehicle.op_base_code_nr 
WHERE purch_order.company_code_nr='1000' LIMIT 7;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT purch_order.user_code_tx as user_code_tx ,purch_order.date_creation 
    as date_creation ,purch_order.purch_order_code_nr as purch_order_code_nr ,purch_order.status as status ,purch_order.purch_order_workflow_code_nr as purch_order_workflow_code_nr ,ppod.vehicle_plate_tx as vehicle_plate_tx ,(Select pd.purch_order_detail_desc_tx from purch_order_detail pd where pd.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr limit 1 ) as purch_order_detail_desc_tx ,(Select pd.purch_order_workflow_desc_tx from purch_order_workflow pd where pd.purch_order_workflow_code_nr = purch_order. purch_order_workflow_code_nr limit 1 ) as purch_order_workflow_desc_tx ,vehicle.op_base_code_nr as op_base_code_nr ,company_division.div_name_tx as div_name_tx ,company_division_op_bases.op_base_name as op_base_name, 
    CASE 
    WHEN purch_order_workflow_code_nr = '3' THEN 1
    WHEN status = '' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END
    AS order_bit
FROM purch_order inner join (Select distinct pod.purch_order_code_nr, pod.vehicle_plate_tx from purch_order_detail pod) ppod on ppod.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr inner join vehicle on vehicle.vehicle_plate_tx = ppod.vehicle_plate_tx inner join company_division on company_division.div_code_nr= purch_order.div_code_nr inner join company_division_op_bases on company_division_op_bases.op_base_code_nr = vehicle.op_base_code_nr 
WHERE purch_order.company_code_nr='1000' 
ORDER BY order_bit
LIMIT 7;
```

Comment: @user3304880 sorry for mistake, I added missing "END" now. It should work

Comment: hi can you please on condition with status its have array value in database i want find a value if not available than also 2nd condition run

Comment: @user3304880 I didn't understand your last comment. Do you have an array value in status field and search for an element in it? If yes, how do you store your array in this field? JSON or serialized?

Comment: yes value like 2,3,4 on column. if  userid=5 than also order by 2nd condition run . means if  value not exist on column .. thanks

Comment: You should use a REGEXP query LIKE 
WHEN status NOT REGEXP CONCAT(',?',userid,',?') THEN 2

Comment: thanks can you please last help me whats should i put there CONCAT(',?',userid,',?') i understand user means what i have but i did not understand about ? mark place .thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

First. You have to format your queries, you can understand better.
Second. When you have formatted this query, you can view where is the location of the order

```js
SELECT purch_order.user_code_tx as user_code_tx ,
    purch_order.date_creation as date_creation ,
    purch_order.purch_order_code_nr as purch_order_code_nr ,
    purch_order.status as status ,
    purch_order.purch_order_workflow_code_nr as purch_order_workflow_code_nr ,
    ppod.vehicle_plate_tx as vehicle_plate_tx ,
    (Select pd.purch_order_detail_desc_tx 
    from purch_order_detail pd 
   where pd.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr 
   limit 1 ) as purch_order_detail_desc_tx ,
    (Select pd.purch_order_workflow_desc_tx 
       from purch_order_workflow pd 
   where pd.purch_order_workflow_code_nr = purch_order. purch_order_workflow_code_nr 
   limit 1 ) as purch_order_workflow_desc_tx ,
    vehicle.op_base_code_nr as op_base_code_nr ,
    company_division.div_name_tx as div_name_tx ,
    company_division_op_bases.op_base_name as op_base_name 
FROM purch_order 
inner join (Select distinct pod.purch_order_code_nr, pod.vehicle_plate_tx from purch_order_detail pod) ppod 
on ppod.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr 
inner join vehicle 
on vehicle.vehicle_plate_tx = ppod.vehicle_plate_tx 
inner join company_division 
on company_division.div_code_nr= purch_order.div_code_nr 
inner join company_division_op_bases 
on company_division_op_bases.op_base_code_nr = vehicle.op_base_code_nr 
WHERE purch_order.company_code_nr='1000'
-- ORDER LOCATION --
LIMIT 7
```

and Third. A simple example order by, with field 1, field 2, field 3.

```js
SELECT purch_order.user_code_tx as user_code_tx ,
    purch_order.date_creation as date_creation ,
    purch_order.purch_order_code_nr as purch_order_code_nr ,
    purch_order.status as status ,
    purch_order.purch_order_workflow_code_nr as purch_order_workflow_code_nr ,
    ppod.vehicle_plate_tx as vehicle_plate_tx ,
    (Select pd.purch_order_detail_desc_tx 
    from purch_order_detail pd 
   where pd.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr 
   limit 1 ) as purch_order_detail_desc_tx ,
    (Select pd.purch_order_workflow_desc_tx 
       from purch_order_workflow pd 
   where pd.purch_order_workflow_code_nr = purch_order. purch_order_workflow_code_nr 
   limit 1 ) as purch_order_workflow_desc_tx ,
    vehicle.op_base_code_nr as op_base_code_nr ,
    company_division.div_name_tx as div_name_tx ,
    company_division_op_bases.op_base_name as op_base_name 
FROM purch_order 
inner join (Select distinct pod.purch_order_code_nr, pod.vehicle_plate_tx from purch_order_detail pod) ppod 
on ppod.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr 
inner join vehicle 
on vehicle.vehicle_plate_tx = ppod.vehicle_plate_tx 
inner join company_division 
on company_division.div_code_nr= purch_order.div_code_nr 
inner join company_division_op_bases 
on company_division_op_bases.op_base_code_nr = vehicle.op_base_code_nr 
WHERE purch_order.company_code_nr='1000'
ORDER BY user_code_tx , date_creation,purch_order_code_nr
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a extra flg in your sql would help.
For example:

```
SELECT 
    ..., 
    IF(purch_order_workflow_code_nr = '3', 1, 2) as powcn_flg,
    IF(status='empty', 1, 2) as statsu_flg
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY powcn_flg ASC, status_flg ASC
```

So maybe your sql will work if you change it into this:

```
SELECT 
purch_order.user_code_tx as user_code_tx ,
purch_order.date_creation as date_creation ,
purch_order.purch_order_code_nr as purch_order_code_nr ,
purch_order.status as status ,purch_order.purch_order_workflow_code_nr as urch_order_workflow_code_nr ,
ppod.vehicle_plate_tx as vehicle_plate_tx ,
(Select pd.purch_order_detail_desc_tx from purch_order_detail pd where pd.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr limit 1 ) as purch_order_detail_desc_tx 
,(Select pd.purch_order_workflow_desc_tx from purch_order_workflow pd where pd.purch_order_workflow_code_nr = purch_order. purch_order_workflow_code_nr limit 1 ) as purch_order_workflow_desc_tx ,
vehicle.op_base_code_nr as op_base_code_nr ,
company_division.div_name_tx as div_name_tx ,
company_division_op_bases.op_base_name as op_base_name ,

IF(purch_order_workflow_code_nr = '3', 1, 2) as powcn_flg,
IF(status='empty', 1, 2) as statsu_flg

FROM purch_order 
inner join (Select distinct pod.purch_order_code_nr, pod.vehicle_plate_tx from purch_order_detail pod) ppod on ppod.purch_order_code_nr = purch_order.purch_order_code_nr 
inner join vehicle on vehicle.vehicle_plate_tx = ppod.vehicle_plate_tx 
inner join company_division on company_division.div_code_nr= purch_order.div_code_nr 
inner join company_division_op_bases on company_division_op_bases.op_base_code_nr = vehicle.op_base_code_nr 
WHERE purch_order.company_code_nr='1000' 
ORDER BY powcn_flg ASC, status_flg ASC
LIMIT 7;
```